# create drop down list from multiple column ignoring blank

Tags: excel, indexing, formula, offset, countif

i use Name Manager to defined a range by this formula

```
=OFFSET(Setting!$E$2,0,0,COUNTA(Setting!$E:$H),4)
```

and add data validation by it's name to the cell i wanna to show drop down list

how can i edit this formula to remove blank options in the drop down list

I ALSO TRY this formula

```
=Setting!$E$2:INDEX(Setting!$E:$E,COUNTIF(Setting!$E:$E,"?*"))
```

but it works only for single column how to edit it to work with multiple columns

Comment: When addressing a named range of higher dimension, Excel tells me: "The list source must be a delimited list, or a reference to single row or column". Can you elaborate how your cells E2:H3, etc look like? How are they filled, what should show up in the dropdown? Maybe it is possible to solve your problem with an inbetween step creating a new list from the given range without blanks.